# How do I mount a Synology remote folder on Android 8.0?

Tags: remote-access, file-sharing, cifs

My phone is not rooted.

I have shared folders on a Synology drive which I can mount on a couple of different Macs running different versions of Mac OSX. I am assuming the folders are published using CIFS/SMB but I cannot mount them on my Android phone using file manager type applications. So far I have tried "ES File Explorer", "Network Browser" and "File Commander" none of which are able to connect.

I can connect to the Synology home page using a browser on the phone so network connectivity is OK. Do I need to disable/enable firewall/sharing settings on the phone?

Comment: Are the Macs also connected via Wifi? Some Wifi router have an option das disallows to communicate Wifi devices with non-Wifi devices.

Comment: Macs are connected by Wifi to the same network the Synology server is on. Android phone is also connected by Wifi to the same network.

Comment: Router is a Netgear D7000v2

Comment: You have a [Synology app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.synology.dsdrive). Try that

Comment: Synology app works fine but I'm not sure it uses CIFS/SMB. I'm looking for a more general solution which doesn't constrain me to using the Synology app.

Comment: On Termux app run `nmap -p139,445 --script smb-enum-shares <IP>` to make sure SMB shares are available. If yes, any file explorer app with SMB (SAMBA/CIFS) support should work. Also `smbclient` can be used from commandline if you manage to get/build the binary for Android. Or you may configure Synology server to use some other protocol e.g. FTP.

Comment: Yes the shares are up on both 139 and 445 according to nmap. Thanks for the command line and the intro to Termux! I guess I'll have to run through all the smb client apps and find one that that works and is stable. Stay tuned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No specific configuration beyond the availability of published shares is required.

Sometimes issues arise due to the stability and capabilities or lack thereof of Android apps to mount the shares. The following apps have been tested and were able to reliably and successfully access SMB shares from the Synology server (at 2 June 2020) using a simple combination of (server) IP Address, username and password:

LAN drive, Cx File Explorer, X-plore, File Commander